# Forward and Backward Pass Activity on Node Diagrams in MS Project 2010

Tags: ms-project

I want to make Forward and Backward Slack Activity on Node Diagrams in MS Project 2010.

I display the Network Diagram view and choose Format > Box Styles. I Click the More
Templates button and in the Data Templates, dialog, select an
existing template and copy it. I Give the new template a name in
the Data Definition dialog window. Towards the bottom of the
Data Definition dialog window in the "Choose Cells" section I
can specify which fields to place in which area.

I want to define four custom number fields ES, LS,
EF, and LF.

ES = ProjectDateDiff([ProjectStart],[EarlyStart])/[MinutesPerDay]

EF = ProjectDateDiff([ProjectStart],[EarlyFinish])/[MinutesPerDay]

LS = ProjectDateDiff([LateStart],[ProjectFinish])/[MinutesPerDay]

LF = ProjectDateDiff([LateFinish],[ProjectFinish])/[MinutesPerDay]

but it seems MS Project doesn't allow formulas or custom fields.

How can I do a formula in a box field or formula ?  Is it possible ?

Comment: 1. The ProjectDateDiff funtion is fine for vba but will generate a syntax error in custom field formulas. (Use ProjDateDiff.)  (In the absence of an explicit calendar specification, the two functions may yield different results in the presence of task calendars or elapsed-duration tasks.)

Comment: 2. Your ordinal-date definition is unconventional, yielding forward-pass dates beginning with zero and ending one less than the project duration.  Also, measuring your late-date ordinals from the Project Finish date can be misleading.  (Conventional terminology has the project starting on day 1, with all other ordinal dates referenced to this.)  Any calendars and milestones will interfere with this.

Comment: Where can I find a list of formula and variables project uses such as ProjDateDiff ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to use formulas directly in the field selector for the network box templates.  Instead, use formulas to populate custom number fields for the ES, EF, LS, and LF ordinals.  Then select these custom fields for the box template.

Comment: Okay, how to do I use formulas to populate the custom number fields for ES, EF, LS and LF ?  Where can I do that in Project ?  I can't seem to find where it is...

Comment: In MSP 2010, click the Custom Fields button on the Properties group of the Project Ribbon.  Choose 4 task number fields, renaming and entering your formula for each.

Comment: are the formulas as i entered above admissible into ms project or not ?

Comment: No they are not.  Haven't you tried them?  To avoid all syntax errors, use the pick-lists for functions and field names that are included in the formula-building dialog in MSP.  You also need to fix the underlying issues with your algorithm.  (Sorry for the reticence - only limited help for school assignments.)

Comment: not looking for assignment help.  just trying to figure out how to put formulas.  i will put some screen shots here and see if i am on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Project does not support the use of formulas in box fields. However, you can use the built-in fields in Microsoft Project to calculate slack values. To do this, follow these steps:

In the Network Diagram view, right-click on a task and select Information.

In the Task Information dialog, go to the Advanced tab.

In the Advanced tab, you will find the Total Slack field, which shows the amount of time that a task can be delayed without delaying the project's finish date.

You can also use the Late Start and Late Finish fields to calculate the amount of slack a task has. The difference between the Late Start and Early Start fields is the amount of backward slack, and the difference between the Late Finish and Early Finish fields is the amount of forward slack.

You can also use the Gantt chart view to see the slack values for tasks. In the Gantt chart view, the slack values are shown as a grey bar in the timescale.